# What is the minimum cost of deploying an iphone app to a single phone from monotouch?

Tags: iphone, ios, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

If I want to deploy a iphone app just to my phone (not the app store to sell to others) what is the minimum things you need to purchase?

Do I have to spend the [$399 on monotouch](https://store.xamarin.com/) and the [$99 yearly apple developer fee](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/) if i just want to build an app that only I will use?

Comment: pretty much yes... also the cost of a mac, and an iP* to test it on

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pay 99 to Apple and 399 to Xamarin to use MonoTouch

Answer (score -2):

You need to pay only $99 yearly apple developer fee .

Comment: but on this page: http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/Guides/Getting_Started/Hello,_World it says "In order to be able to deploy to a device, you need a properly provisioned device and a non-evaluation version of MonoTouch (the evaluation version only allows deploying to the simulator)"

Comment: _"you need a properly provisioned device"_ > This means, you need a developer account.

Comment: @frank nirania: you are wrong, you also need a commercial license of MonoTouch to deploy to a device. The $99 iOS Developer subscription is not enough. You can create the necessary provisioning profiles for your device, but the evaluation version of MonoTouch will not deploy to it.

Comment: It is a bit confusing, the asker doesn't say they *have* to use MonoTouch. Technically you could just pay the $99 fee and used XCode and Objective-C. Although I would recommend MonoTouch for any C# dev.

Comment: The title of the question includes the word "monotouch" :-)

Comment: @DimitrisTavlikos Dude see what he has written there is no need of monotouch if you want to use app in your iphone .He hasn't mentioned in question detail regarding mono touch by the way thanks for making my answer -1.